# How to create custom validation within the same controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form which performs the inserting function, the related method is :

```
public function addthread(Request $request) {

    //validate
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|unique:thread|max:255',
        'num_opt' => $this->checkOpt($request),
    ]); 

}
```

I want to use a custom function to validate the `num_opt` elements,:

```
protected function checkOpt($request, Validator $validator) {

    //$num_opt = $request->input('num_opt');
    if ($request->has('$num_opt')) {
         //$validator->errors()->add ??
         How to customize the error message?
    }
    //die();
}
```

Questions:

- Is the above code practice is wrong or not?
- How can I access `$validator` and customize the error message in the `checkOpt` function?

Comment: As the documentation suggest, you could extend it in your app service provider boot method:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: @lamzozo is there any ways just add the message? i use $message->add('abc','abc'); , but the errors not print out

Comment: Yes, you could add the message to your current lang file, in `resources/lang/en/validation.php`, add another key to the array, like `"abc" => "My error message"`.